# offline retina map tiles too big

Tags: swift, mapkit, retina-display, mktileoverlay

This question has no answer since august.
I've found no question identical.
I hope it's clear enough.
There seems to be few questions on maps but someone must know the answer.

I'm trying to display an offline map using 512x512 tiles. I have the tiles named like 22524@x2.png
if I use the 256x256 tiles the map displays correctly, but the 512 tiles only show a quarter of each tile. 
here's my code

```
//Get the URL template to the map tiles
let baseURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.absoluteString

//let urlTemplate = baseURL.stringByAppendingString("osmm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png/")
let urlTemplate = baseURL.stringByAppendingString("two/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png/")

print(urlTemplate)


let carte_indice = MKTileOverlay(URLTemplate:urlTemplate)

carte_indice.geometryFlipped = false

carte_indice.canReplaceMapContent = true

carte_indice.maximumZ = 18
carte_indice.minimumZ = 16



self.mapView.addOverlay(carte_indice)
```

What do I need to add to get the tiles to display correctly? 
Is a map using 256x256 tiles on a retina screen acceptable  by apple?

Comment: I'm using 256x256 and I have no problems. Apple approved it and it's live on the AppStore

Comment: Thanks for that information. I seem to have been barking up a non existant tree.